# How to center a <div>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See my code at [codepen](http://codepen.io/jackyef/pen/RKRvGZ)

I'm trying to horizontally center the circle progress bar in the page, I tried setting `margin: 0 auto;` on the div, it didn't work. I, also, tried setting  `text-align: center` on the parent div and setting the div to `display: inline-block`, no success as well.

This is the element in the HTML I'm trying to center:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="timer"> <!-- this one should be centered -->
          <div class="c100 p50 big">
              <span>50%</span>
              <div class="slice">
                <div class="bar"></div>
                <div class="fill"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the CSS I'm applying on the element:

```
.col-md-12{
  width: 100%;
}
.timer{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` or set it to `none` in `.c100` css class.

```
.c100 {
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks [rupinderjeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3682535/rupinderjeet). New to SF.

Comment: Ahh, this is the correct answer! Thanks! That's such an silly error to miss on! I'll accept this as an answer when stackoverflow allows me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this.

```html
<center>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="timer"> <!-- this one should be centered -->
            <div class="c100 p50 big">
                <span>50%</span>
                <div class="slice">
                  <div class="bar"></div>
                  <div class="fill"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left;`from `.c100` class to center the div.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing CSS rules with:

```
.col-md-12 {
  text-align: center;
}
.timer {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  <div class="timer"> <!-- this one should be centered -->
>
> .timer{
>   width: 100%;
>   margin: 0 auto;
> }
> ```

It **is** centered. It is also 100% wide, so being in the center is the same as being left or right aligned. It takes up **all** the space.

You need to set a smaller width in order for it to *noticeably* appear in the center.

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you wanted:

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggMqWv)

I added:

```
.timer {display: flex}
```

and also added a new class to it's only child

```
.align {margin: 0 auto !important;}
```

as `.c100` overrides `margin`s.